# Conditionally disabling text boxes using Vue

Tags: html, vue.js

I want to disable the Level of play: text box when there is nothing written in the Sport / team / school: text box. How can I do this?

```
    <div class="field">
      <label class="label">Sport / team / school:</label>
        <div class="control">
          <input v-model="form.sportTeamSchool" class="input" type="text" placeholder="Text">
        </div>
    </div>  

    <div class="field">
      <label class="label">Level of play:</label>
        <div class="control">
          <input v-model="form.levelOfPlay" class="input" type="text" placeholder="Text">
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have tried using

```
<input v-model="form.levelOfPlay" :disabled="sportTeamSchool == ''" class="input" type="text" placeholder="Text">
```

to conditionally disable it but to no avail, and it seems to be the only option I can find online to do so. Is there something wrong with my code that doesn't allow this to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```html
<input v-model="form.levelOfPlay" :disabled="!sportTeamSchool.length" class="input" type="text" placeholder="Text">
```

A computed property would work as well. But in this case it is unnecessary and is just more code then needed.

Comment: If sportTeamSchool was a number input instead, how would I change that to disable levelOfPlay when sportTeamSchool is empty or has a value of 0?

Comment: Since `0` equals `false` and anything above `0` equals true, just use `:disabled="sportTeamSchool"`.

Comment: @Alex however, if the `sportTeamSchool` is `undefined` this will not work. But if it is `undefined` you probably designed your code false as it should be either `0` or `> 0`.

Comment: @Alex I forgot that you want to disable it if nothing is written. Therefore, you have to add an exclamation mark.

Comment: Yup, it works fine. Sorry for not updating you, but it was an error elsewhere in my code that did not allow your answer to work. Thanks for helping out and continuing to check-in!

Answer (score 0):

Just add and Exclamation mark.
I think this will work just fine.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    form: {
    sportTeamSchool:"",
    levelOfPlay:""
    }
  },
  methods: {
  
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="field">
      <label class="label">Sport / team / school:</label>
        <div class="control">
          <input v-model="form.sportTeamSchool" class="input" type="text" placeholder="Text">
        </div>
    </div>  

    <div class="field">
      <label class="label">Level of play:</label>
        <div class="control">
          <input 
            v-model="form.levelOfPlay" 
            class="input" 
            type="text" 
            placeholder="Text"
            :disabled="!form.sportTeamSchool"
            >
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to work perfectly fine when I run the code snippet on here, but when I copy it over and add just the HTML and body tags, it doesn't seem to work anymore. Where could the problem be?